# java classes changed into wrong things

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

i was coding a program and there was no problem , but after i close android studio and re-open it , some of my Java Classes are not shown correct in android studio , for example one my classes is like the code below

i check the file and open this class with notepad and notepad show me the file correct , but android studio seem to have some problem 
what should i do about this ?

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Kalam22222-core.core-1.0">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/core/build/libs/core-1.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go in "Build -> Clean Project", if that doesn't work you can try "File -> Sync with Files" and "File -> Sync with Gradle". In case this doesn't work either, you can go to "File -> Invalidate caches/restart".